# Can't see echo output of shell script using xinetd

Tags: bash, shell, iptables, xinetd

I've created a simple shell script named /usr/sbin/helloworld

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
mkdir ~/itran
read -p "Say Hello : " hello
echo "$hello"
exit 0
```

I created /etc/xinetd.d/testservice-map as below

```
service testservice
{
    port            = 4079
    socket_type     = stream
    protocol        = tcp
    wait            = no
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/helloworld
    server_args     = test
}
```

and added the line below in /etc/services

```
testservice 4079/tcp
```

I've assigned one IP to my host and added an IPTABLE rule to redirect the request on port 22 of that IP to port 4079 of localhost

Now when I SSH to that IP using putty from another machine, from the logs (/var/log/messages) I can see that my service is being executed on the host but I can't see the "Hello World" message.
The directory "itran" gets created but I can't see the echo message nor can I input any value.

I'm new to this. Kindly let me know if any more information is needed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you have is that ssh does a lot more than you expect.

What happens is:

- you start ssh
- your ssh client sends an initiation of the session
- your script launches and sends "Hello world"
- your ssh client expects a server public key, but gets the hello world
- You ssh-client terminates

With some verbose-options on your ssh-client, you can probably observe this behaviour.

Now, other clients do not have a first protocol handshake. If you have a telnet-client, you will probably get your expected result with

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 4079
```

Otherwise, try `nc`.

Comment: Is there any way I can use SSH? Can I make my script do the handshake, accept the username and password and then display something? Is there a library for that?

Comment: There are C-libraries, Python's Twisted seems to do something like that, but don't go there. It is almost certainly not what you want.The result will not be a simple script like you produced.